# Return false is not prevent calling form submitting in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

On a form submit I am calling following function.

```
function confirmSubmit() {
    var checkedAtLeastOne = false;
    var checkboxs = document.getElementsByName("reportColumns");
    var reportId = $('#reportId').val();

    console.log(checkboxs.length);
    for(var i = 0, l = checkboxs.length; i < l; i++) {
        if(checkboxs[i].checked) {
            checkedAtLeastOne = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(checkedAtLeastOne) {
        if(!reportId) {
            alert('Report ID cannot be empty');
            return false;
        } else {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhttp.open("GET", "checkreportid.action?reportId=" + reportId, true);
            xhttp.send();

            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function (e) {
                if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("checkreportid").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
                    var reportid = $('#reportid').val();
                    console.log("reportId->" + reportId);
                    console.log("reportid->" + $('#reportid').val());
                    if(reportid == reportId) {
                        alert("Duplicate Report ID!");
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    } else {
        alert("You must select atleast one column");
        //e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here if the **reportid** equals to **reportId** it gives the alert (Duplicate Report ID) but it calls the action. **return false** is not prevent calling the action.

I am calling the function as below.

```
<s:form action="savereport" namespace="/" validate="true"
        onsubmit="return confirmSubmit()">
```

**EDITED**

Now I am trying following. If the report ID is empty it gives relevant alert message (Report ID cannot be empty). It it is not empty it calls the **checkreportid** action but it doesn't give duplicate error message even if there are duplicate report ids. It calls the form submitting action.

function confirmSubmit() {
        var checkedAtLeastOne = false;
        var checkboxs = document.getElementsByName("reportColumns");
        var reportId = $('#reportId').val();

```
    console.log(checkboxs.length);
    for (var i = 0, l = checkboxs.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (checkboxs[i].checked) {
            checkedAtLeastOne = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!reportId) {
        alert('Report ID cannot be empty');
        return false;
    } else {
        ////////
        $.ajax({
            url: "<s:url action='checkreportid'/>",
            type: "GET",
            data: {reportId: reportId},
            dataType: "text/javascript",
            traditional: true,
            statusCode: {
                200: function (data) {
                    console.log(data.responseText);
                    document.getElementById("checkreportid").innerHTML = data.responseText;
                    var reportid = $('#reportid').val();
                    console.log("reportId->"+reportId);
                    console.log("reportid->"+reportid);
                    if (reportid==reportId) {
                        alert("Duplicate Report ID!");
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        if (!checkedAtLeastOne) {
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            alert("You must select atleast one column");
                            return false;
                        } 
                    }

                }
            }

        }); 
    }       
}
```

What am I missing with my code ?

Comment: How are you calling the validate function?

Comment: Side-note: Why are you not using `$.ajax(..)` if you are already using jquery? It saves you from messing with readyStates and the like.

Comment: @Sumurai8 I am using jquery

Comment: @Oda plz see my edited question

Comment: The problem here is that the ajax call is not synchronous, so the function makes that call and then just exits, without returning false, so the form submit continues.  Some time after that, the ajax request is completed but it's too late.

Comment: Can anyone help me to use $.ajax

Comment: See [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: @Archer +that it is strange to assume that a call to a different (anonymous) function in a `.onreadystatechange`-handler would cause the "return false" to fall through to the validate-function.

Comment: @Sumurai8 It's returning `undefined` as the ajax call has not completed before the function.  This requires a callback after the call is complete, which would then submit the form or not.

Comment: @Archer I know, I know. I just wanted to point out that even if this call was synchronous, and the handler would be defined before the call was made, it is still a different function. As such a return statement in the handler function will not do anything in the validate-function.

Comment: @Sumurai8 Yes, I see what you mean now.  Of course, you're correct.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the asyncronous nature of a `XMLHttpRequest`.  You are returning false in a callback function, not in the `onsubmit` handler.

You should look into doing what you want without an `XMLHttpRequest` or use a syncronous request (this is not reccomended and disabled in some browsers).

The reccomended option is to stop the form submitting all the time with

```
e.preventDefault();
return false;
```

And to manually submit the form with a `XMLHttpRequest` in the original callback if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `XMLHttpRequest` is aysnchronous.

Your call to

```
xhttp.send();
```

returns immediately and therefore that `if-else` branch doesn't have a `return false`.

The return statements in your code boil down to:

```
if(checkedAtLeastOne) {
    if(!reportId) {
        return false;
    } else {
    }
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Note `xhttp.open("GET", "checkreportid.action?reportId=" + reportId, false);` would make the request synchronous. In this case `.onreadystatechange(..)` should not be used though.

Comment: @Sumurai8 that *would* make it synchronous, but that isn't what's in the code currently.  The question was "why does return false not stop the submit" - it was not "how do I make it stop the submit" - the answer I provided does explain *why* this is the case for the provided code.

Answer (score 0):

You should add preventDefault method to the form element like below.

```
  <form onsubmit='event.preventDefault(); return confirmSubmit();'>
        <input type='submit' />
    </form>
```

Answer (score -3):

Use return in onsubmit event to trigger return false action,

```
<form onsubmit = "return confirmSubmit()"> 
</form>
```